# Android Chrome web view doesn't redraw on navigation

Tags: android, android-webview, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat

When upgrading to Android 7 (where System webview was replaced by Chrome), the webview has repainting issues and will not redraw after navigation unless I rotate the device.

I managed to work around this by setting        **android:hardwareAccelerated="false"** in the manifest.

Is there another workaround for this problem, as the webview appears to be sluggish after this change?

Comment: try this advance webview https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now a confirmed Chrome Webview bug.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=704212